# SQL - How to select/delete rows with the max value depending on two others

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm an intern in a property rental company. I'm in charge of developping the CRM under Symfony.

So, ones of my entities are properties (houses) and their availabilities. See the table structure below.

[image]

The problem I'm facing for now, is that the availabilities had been defined for each day (e.g. 28/01, 29/01, 30/01) instead of being defined for a range of day (e.g. 28/01 -> 30/01). So, the table is really heavy (~710 000 rows). Furthermore, before we changed the way of editing an availability, it created a new row for a same date instead of editing it. So, there are a lot of duplications in this table.

What I want, is to lighten the DB by keeping only the rows which have the max value in `date_modif_availabilities` for the same `date_availabilities` and `id_properties`.

For example, if I have these rows (availabilities_duplications):

[image]

I only want to keep the row with the latest modif like this (availabilities_keep_max_value) :

[image]

The thing is, I don't know enough the SQL language. I'm able to write few basics scripts but not complex subqueries. Even with code samples that I found.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Idea of "deduplicating" is not good for the future, my suggestion is to make a view (materialized if big) but not to delete "old stuff" as in the future it may be useful again to build a datawarehouse.

Comment: You are totally right @DDS. It's never a good thing to delete datas. I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by « make a view » ?

Comment: Create a view where you only "filter" the data you need, and then you use the view as table so you have a "slim".   `CREATE VIEW slim_table AS SELECT * FROM heavy_table WHERE <filtering conditions for needed rows>`

Comment: I'm really sorry, I had never heard about VIEW in SQL. Thank you so much for revealing it to me ! It's not exactly the answer of the question but you taught me something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the elements for which no element with greater modified date exists.
Something like this:

```
SELECT avl1.*
FROM   availabilities avl1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   availabilities avl2
                   WHERE  avl1.date_availabilities = avl2.date_availabilities
                     AND  avl1.id_properties = avl2.id_properties
                     AND  avl2.date_modif_availabilities > avl1.date_modif_availabilities);
```

This of course has the pre-condition that the combination of the three columns `date_availabilities`, `id_properties` and `date_modif_availabilities` is unique.

Furthermore, it seems that all columns (except the PK) may be `NULL`. Looks kinda odd to me.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your solution @Robert . The script is loading... I will let you know when it's finished.

Comment: I tested your query but, due to the huge number of datas (~710 000), the script is endless... And I'm in local so I can't imagine the result on server... I'm really sorry... To see the result, I created a small table et your script works like a charm. So this is a good answer as well as @Yogesh Sharma 's solution. I'm new on Stack Overflow and I saw it's not possible to mark two answers... What do I have to do ?

Comment: @Minilouze: Both answers seem to work. Just pick the one you prefer as the correct one. As far as the query is concerned: can you put an index on the columns data_availabilities and id_properties? Should be a single index on the combination of these columns.

Comment: Ok thank you. Like I said, I'm not a SQL expert... What is the difference between having several indexes and having single index for several columns ?

Comment: You might consider doing an (online) course of SQL and in particular MySQL. It's not that easy to explain within a single comment.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where id_availabilities = (select t1.id_availabilities
                           from table t1 
                           where t1.id_properties = t.id_properties and
                                 t1.date_availabilities = t.date_availabilities
                           order by t1.date_modif_availabilities desc
                           limit 1
                          );
```

However, if you have concern about the *performance*, then you want index on `(id_properties, date_availabilities and id_availabilities)`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I will test it after @Robert 's solution and let you know the result.

Comment: I tested your query but, due to the huge number of datas (~710 000), the script is endless... And I'm in local so I can't imagine the result on server... I'm really sorry... To see the result, I created a small table et your script works like a charm. So this is a good answer as well as @Robert Kock 's solution. I'm new on Stack Overflow and I saw it's not possible to mark two answers... What do I have to do ?